# Відмінюванє слів на штиб „житє“

Tags: відмінювання, альтернативні-правописи

Як вже бачно з назви питання тут не про чинного — 2015 року — чи навіть харківського правопису — 1928 року, а про правопису Желехівського, як я сам взнав.

Я [натрапив](//zbruc.eu/node/81889) на

> Іван Франко писав: «Де **житє**, там і поезія, але **житє** тільки там, де ідея — і зловити гру **житя** значить зловити невидимий і пахучий етер ідеї»

Не знаю чи правда Іван таке писав, але напевно вживав, оскільки збережений твір з такою назвою: [**Житє** і слово](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%94_%D1%96_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE). А [перелік правописів](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81#%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%B7_XIX_%D1%81%D1%82.)) вказує саме на [желехівку](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), там також згадано про Франка і приклади таких слів:

> В іменниках середнього роду не відбувалося подовження шелестівок і писано закінчення є відповідно до наддніпрянського я: *зїлє*, *житє*, *знанє*;

[Шелестівка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) — це приголосний. Гадаю, відмінювання теж буде відміним від чинного — і саме це мене цікавить. Як розумію, слово є очевидним середнього роду, як зараз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вікі підказує

> Желехівку закріплено в «Руській граматиці» С. Смаль-Стоцького й Т. Ґартнера, що вийшла у світ 1893 року у Львові *[…]*

Ця [стаття](https://zbruc.eu/node/66463) правопису (правда, 1892 року) про те, однак не дуже розказує про відмінювань, лиш наведено приклади, причому без підпису відмінків і з иншим порядком — я визначив лиш за иншими словами і порівнянями з чинними, нп. *часть*, *річ*.

Наш приклад, приведу до лїпшого вигляду з підписами, але без зміни порядка:

| відмінок | однина | множина |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *називний* | нарікан-є | нарікан-я |
| *родовий* | нарікан-я | нарікань |
| *давальний* | нарікан-ю | нарікан-ям |
| *знахідний* | нарікан-є | нарікан-я |
| *кличний* | нарікан-є | нарікан-я |
| *орудний* | нарікан-єм | нарікан-ями |
| *місцевий* | нарікан-ї,-ю | нарікан-ях |

Для порівняня чинне:

| відмінок | однина | множина |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *називний* | наріка́нн-я | наріка́нн-я |
| *родовий* | наріка́нн-я | наріка́нь |
| *давальний* | наріка́нн-ю | наріка́нн-ям |
| *знахідний* | наріка́нн-я | наріка́нн-я |
| *кличний* | наріка́нн-я | наріка́нн-я |
| *орудний* | наріка́нн-ям | наріка́нн-ями |
| *місцевий* | наріка́нн-і,-ю | наріка́нн-ях |

Цїкаво, шчо кличний за порядком на 5 місцї. Також з приємного:

- нема збігів між множиною та одниною
- виглядає і поводе ся як звичаєвий [але мякий, тобто з *ь*] середнїй рід, для порівняня:

  | відмінок | однина | множина |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | *називний* | сел-о́ | се́л-а |
  | *родовий* | сел-а́ | сіл |
  | *давальний* | сел-у́ | се́л-ам |
  | *знахідний* | сел-о́ | се́л-а |
  | *кличний* | сел-о́ | се́л-а |
  | *орудний* | сел-о́м | се́л-ами |
  | *місцевий* | сел-і́,-у́ | се́л-ах |

Comment: Це і є звичайний середній рід. Від м’якої відміни його різнить лише фонетичний перехід   -ьjе(мъ) > --ьja(мъ), з наступним подовженням приголосного.